# How to merge cells in same column

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to create a report like this:

[image]

Left column rows have to be merged and only one record. Maybe its rotation may be vertical. On the right column, it can be two,three,.. or fifteen records and left column must stretch. Can anyone help me?